# Change time of 'next_execution_date' on Airflow in 'BashOperator'

Tags: python-3.x, airflow, pendulum

I am trying to launch a process through the Bash Operator.

```
bash =BashOperator(
        task_id='Trigger some dag',
        bash_command='airflow trigger_dag -e "{{ next_execution_date }}" some_dag_id',
        dag=dag,
    )
```

I know that Airflow uses Pendulum to manage datetimes, so by looking at the documentation, I tried the '`.set`' method

```
bash =BashOperator(
        task_id='Trigger some dag',
        bash_command='airflow trigger_dag -e "{{ next_execution_date.set(hour=someHour) }}" some_dag_id',
        dag=dag,
    )
```

but I get the error `'pendulum.pendulum.Pendulum object' has no attribute 'set'`.

I could not find further documentation.

How could I change the hour of the next_execution_date?

Answer (score 0):

Try this (untested):

```py
bash =BashOperator(
        task_id='Trigger some dag',
        bash_command='airflow trigger_dag -e "{{ macros.ds_add(next_execution_date, 1)}}" some_dag_id',
        dag=dag,
    )
```

Why are you triggering a dag from within a DAG?